# buildToolsVersion 28.0.3 - Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, android-studio

My build.gradle is

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig:
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27

dependencies:
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Got this error

```
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/ericji/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-media-compat-27.1.1.aar/3ace11096114d261fddf79eb9c08154c/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml","position":{"startLine":5,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":248,"endColumn":66,"endOffset":310}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
:app:processDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
```

Android studio is upgraded to 3.2.1, so I have to use 28.0.3.

Does anyone get this issue? How to fix it? much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried bumping the compileSdkVersion and support library major versions to 28? You can leave the targetSdk set to 27 to avoid having to update anything else in your app for now.

Comment: Thanks. Tried and got the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

With Android Gradle Plugin 3.0+, you no longer are required to specify the buildToolsVersion version. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools